# Trying to use code from another project by including it in my build path

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out a way to share code across projets.  this is what i did

1. created a project called sharecode and made the following class

package codelib.com;

public class cShape  {

}

1. made a android project called testsharecode
2. whent to properties->java build path and clicked on projects at the top.
3. clicked add, and added sharecode
4. created a class to try include the cShape class from the sharecode project

package com.example.testsharecode;
import codelib.com

public class parent {
    cShape test;
}

On my import i get a error saying 
"only a type can be imported, cadelib resolves to a package"
on cShape i get a error saying the def does not exist.

How can project testsharecode use the code in projetc sharecode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the following method :

1. right click on the distination projet, Build Path -> configure build path
2. chose project then select testsharecode

back in your distiation project now you should be able to use your public classes.
hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes this is what IU did, It looks like my inport should have been import codelib.com.* instead of import codelib.com.

Comment: yes, I didn't pay attention to that, a good practice is to simply use auto-completion(ctrl space) or ctrl shift o for your imports, eclipse will take care of the rest, unless their are many possibilities. In that case you'll be asked to precise class to be imported.